# How do i get shell_exec functions to run in home directory?

Tags: php, linux, apache, sftp, shell-exec

I have a php script running on Apache on a Pi4

```
<?php
chdir('/')
echo shell_exec('sftp User@localhost')
?>
```

This code doesn't show or do anything. I suspect it has something to do with www-data permissions

Anybody knows how I can run a sftp client through shell_exec?????
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect to see on the web page when you run this code?

Comment: `/` is the root directory, not the home directory.

Comment: `sftp` is an interactive program, you can't run it like that from a web script. If you want to access an SFTP server, use [ssh2_sftp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

Comment: ssh2_sftp solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ssh2_sftp](http://php.net/ssh2_sftp), like this:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('localhost', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

Comment: how would i get shell_exec to execute commands as a superuser? for example, if i want to `eject /dev/sda1` that command wont execute as the html directory does not have sufficient permissions to run as a superuser. how would i make changes accordingly.